# jQuery beforeSend !confirm alerts twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button that, when clicked, triggers a borrame() function:

```
$("div").on ("click", ".bBorrar", function () {
    var id = $(this.parentNode.parentNode).attr("id");
    var tabla = $("table").attr("id");
    borrame(id, tabla);
});
```

The borrame functions is the following:

```
function borrame(id, tabla) {
    $.ajax({
       url: "includes/borra.php",
       type: "POST",
       data: {id: id, tabla: tabla},
       beforeSend: function()  {
            if  (!confirm("Are you sure?")){
            exit(0);
            }
        },
       success: function(data) {
           alert(data);
           var este = "#"+id;
           $(este).remove();
       },
       error: function() {
           alert ("Error");
       }
    });
}
```

What I don't understand is why the "Are you sure?" confirm appears twice when I click the button. Any ideas?

**UPDATE** This is the HTML:

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>info</th><th>info</th><th>info</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="1">
        <td>info</td>
        <td>info</td>
        <td>info</td>
        <td><button class="bBorrar btn btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**UPDATE 2**: The HTML is dinamically generated by PHP.

Comment: Try putting a console.log(1) inside the on click function, and a console.log(2) inside the borrame function, and see which fires twice.

Comment: You have some event bubbling. Use `e.stopPropagation()` in your click handler.

Comment: Show your HTML, your handler is probably being called  twice because it's bubbling up the tree

Comment: Your supplied HTML does not have any div in it, how are you getting the event to trigger in the first place?

Comment: @apokryfos The div is the inmediatly supperior, non-dinamically generated HTML element.

Comment: @miguelmald your event will trigger as many times as there are `div` ancestors to the table. How many would that be?

Comment: Far more than two. I've tried putting a ID to the `div`, but the it keeps triggering twice.

Answer (score 1):

try with `$(document)` object, instead of `div`, multiple divs can make multiple requests.

```
$(document).on("click", ".bBorrar", function () {
    var id = $(this.parentNode.parentNode).attr("id");
    var tabla = $("table").attr("id");
    borrame(id, tabla);
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying or how this would solve the problem

Comment: The button is dinamically generated, so this does not work.